# d3 - Adding a particle effect inside an SVG element on click

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I'm looking to highlight to users the selections they've made by applying a particle effect like this to my SVG paths:
https://bl.ocks.org/armollica/07123dbc0815fb43decb

Thing is, it's quite a technical ask and I'm struggling to psuedo-code the way about building this.

I have attached what I have so far. What I am thinking is, once the item is clicked a class called 'selected' populates. From there, the particle effect should show in order to distinguish this.

I know this is a huge ask! I have struggled to comprehend how I can insert this particle effect into the mask of my visualization, but as I understand it a lot of people are looking to learn similar. Is this something you can help with?

```js
var w = 800;
var h = 800;

const svg = d3.select('#radial-chart')
.append('svg')
.attr('width', w)
.attr('height', h);



var arcData = [
    {domain: '1', innerRadius: 0, outerRadius: (h/1.75), startAngle: Math.PI * -20/180, endAngle: Math.PI * 20/180},
    {domain: '2', innerRadius: 0, outerRadius: (h/1.25)
, startAngle: Math.PI * 20/180, endAngle: Math.PI * 60/180}
];

// Order needs to be from JSON
var colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
.domain(["1", "2"])
.range(["#E8A82B", "#000000"]);
const arc = d3.arc()
const slices = arcData.map(d => arc(d));

const handleMouseOver = (d, i, n) => {
    svg.selectAll('path')
    .transition().duration(300)
        .style('opacity', 0.2);

    d3.select(n[i])
    .transition().duration(300)
        .style('opacity', 1)

}

const handleMouseOut = (d, i, n) => {
    svg.selectAll('path')
    .transition().duration(300)
        .style('opacity', 1);
}


svg.selectAll('path')
    .data(slices)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(325,550)')
    .attr("d", d => d)
    .attr("id", (d, i) => "arc" + i)
    .style("fill", (d,i) => colorScale(i))
    .style("z-index", 100)
    .style("opacity", 0.85)
    .on('mouseover', handleMouseOver)
    .on('mouseout', handleMouseOut)
    .on('click', function() {
        d3.select(this).classed("selected", d3.select(this).classed("selected") ? false : true);
      })
```

```css
.selected {
    opacity: 1!important
}
```

```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
    <div id="radial-chart"></div>
```

Comment: You'd need something like [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/bumbeishvili/19ff0e9ab375077728703b08cc4f6964), but keep in mind that you have a pie chart with a Bezier curve, so you need to calculate several points on that curve to know where to stop drawing/bounce the points. Also, he uses a `canvas` object,  because 1000 points in SVG becomes slow, in Canvas it doesn't. If you want that many points, use [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/boeric/aa80b0048b7e39dd71c8fbe958d1b1d4) on how to use canvas within SVG.

Comment: Thanks again Ruben!